# ReactJS - 'valueLink' is deprecated set `value` and `onChange` instead

Tags: reactjs

I am currently learning ReactJS following a tutorial by the excellent Wes Bos, however I have reached a section regarding 2 way data binding and it seems the method Wes is teaching is now deprecated. I now need to try and find the correct method for the code below or I will not be able to progress with the tutorial..

Ok so the issue I am having is with "valueLink", console says I should be using 'value' and 'onChange' in its place. Could anyone help me out with this issue, seems a lot of the learning involved with react is trying to stay on top of all the deprecated elements!

```
<input type="text" valueLink={linkState('fishes.' + key + '.name')}/>
```

Answer (score 10):

> Ok so the issue I am having is with "valueLink", console says I should be using 'value' and 'onChange' in its place. Could anyone help me out with this issue, seems a lot of the learning involved with react is trying to stay on top of all the deprecated elements!

Value Link is the design pattern, Facebook cannot deprecate it. They will just remove *their implementation* of that pattern from the React core. Read through this article for explanation about the pattern:

https://medium.com/@gaperton/managing-state-and-forms-with-react-part-1-12eacb647112#.5o63wmy72

> No easy/messy 2-way data binding with modern React!

You don't have to use *their implementation* of value links (it's very limited anyway). And you don't have to write everywhere these stupid callbacks either. This one, which is presented in the article, is way more powerful.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/valuelink

Comment: Note that `valuelink` doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.

Comment: It is pretty simple and basically feature-complete, there is nothing to maintain.

Comment: Yet, maybe I will release the "final" version based on the experience of its usage during the last three years.

Answer (score 1):

No easy/messy 2-way data binding with modern React!

What console is trying to tell you is that you should use the "value" property to define the value of that input, and the "onChange" property to define the function that will trigger the change.

So, you'd have:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  value={name} 
  onChange={(event) => { onNameChange(event.target.value)}}
/>
```

And it would be the onNameChange method that would cause your "name" variable to change to the input's new value.

Do note, that onNameChange method would be something you have defined yourself, there's nothing special about it; it could be as elegant or hacky as you'd like. Nowadays, you'd probably want to have it dispatching an action that would update the single source of truth that is your app's state. Take a look at [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux), you do have a lot of learning ahead of you ;-)

Comment: why the extra arrow fn?
I would probably try to simply use `onChange={onNameChange}` and the 'event' will be passed to onNameChange anyways... sometimes you don't need to bind or use arrow functions for this.

Comment: @rafaelbiten Of course what you are suggesting is a very valid option! I just felt having onNameChange expect just the value makes things feel more direct, more consistent to the old 2-way binding methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the tutorial is for an older version of ReactJS because [ReactLink is deprecated.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html)

The recommendation is that you use the onChange event handler to set the state value:

```
<input type="text" name="name" onChange={ this.onInputChange.bind(this) } />
```

Basically, you have to create a method called `onInputChange()` and handle the change there.

This is just for reference, in the end, you should probably just refer to a newer tutorial. I recommend [this one.](http://www.hackingwithreact.com/read/1/1/begin-at-the-beginning-chapter-one)