# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at Input (tags.js:64)

Tags: reactjs

What I'm doing wrong ?

I'm trying to use [valuelink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/valuelink) to manager my form state, but I'm getting a error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>       at Input (tags.js:64)
>       at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:10400)

First I created a wrapper input ..

```
// MyInput
import Link, { LinkedComponent } from 'valuelink';
import { Input } from 'valuelink/tags';
export default class extends LinkedComponent /* I tryed extends from PureComponent too */ {
  state = {};
  render() {
    <Input {...rest} />
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to use in another component ..

```
import Link, { LinkedComponent } from 'valuelink';
import MyInput from 'components/MyInput';
export default class extends LinkedComponent {
  render() {
    const linked = this.linkAll();
    return <MyInput valueLink={linked.fieldTest} />
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to name the classes? You're extending them yes, but not naming them.

Comment: I don't need to name the classes. Just export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix.. I need to declare explicitly all fields in state.

```
state = {
  field1: undefined
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this answer is correct:

```
state = {
  field1: undefined
};
```

The reason is that there's no way for the `component.linkAll()` to guess the possible properties of an empty state. They have to be initialized. Also, it's a good practice for a number of other reasons.

Maybe, I should add it to the documentation (I'm an author of `valuelink` package). And of course, it's not deprecated. It's "feature complete" :).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently valueLink is deprecated (and, quite some time ago). Use value instead and onChange. See [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008476/reactjs-valuelink-is-deprecated-set-value-and-onchange-instead) that explains it.

Comment: `valuelink` that I use is not from React.. is from [this library](https://github.com/Volicon/NestedLink)